# How can I collect data by filename in jq?

Tags: jq

I have a few JSON files such as:

```
run1.json                                   run2.json
{                                           {
  "Paris": 1, "London": 2                     "Paris": 7, "London": 8, "Perth": 9
}                                           }
```

I would like to get out a file such as

```
{
  "Paris": { "run1": 1, "run2": 7 },
  "London": { "run1": 2, "run2": 8 },
  "Perth": { "run2": 9 }
}
```

The filenames can retain their .json extension, that's not important. I know I can get the filename using `input_filename`, but struggle to aggregate the data in that way. Is this possible in jq?

If it's a huge difficulty that some files contain more cities than others, I could filter them so that the subset is fixed over all files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this approach using `reduce`:

```bash
jq -n '
  reduce (inputs | to_entries[]) as {$key, $value} ({};
    .[$key][input_filename | rtrimstr(".json")] = $value
  )
' run1.json run2.json
```

```json
{
  "Paris": {
    "run1": 1,
    "run2": 7
  },
  "London": {
    "run1": 2,
    "run2": 8
  },
  "Perth": {
    "run2": 9
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Not particularly efficient, but fairly readable:

```
$ jq -n '
def merge: reduce .[] as $x ({}; . * $x);
[inputs | map_values({ (input_filename|rtrimstr(".json")): . })] | merge
' run*.json
```

[oguz ismail](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10248678/oguz-ismail) suggested a more efficient solution in the comments that doesn't require building an array first:

```
$ jq -n '
def merge(s): reduce s as $x ({}; . * $x);
merge(inputs | map_values({ (input_filename|rtrimstr(".json")): . }))
' run*.json
```

Output:

```json
{
  "Paris": {
    "run1": 1,
    "run2": 7
  },
  "London": {
    "run1": 2,
    "run2": 8
  },
  "Perth": {
    "run2": 9
  }
}
```